# C++ unordered_map especify types on runtime

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Is there any way that I could define an `unordered_map<*,*>` var and depending a case or other redefine it with the appropriate types?

I'm reading some binaries files and the format is different for each so depending the formats it can by `<int, string>, <short, string>, <int, int>, etc..`

The only way I can think of is to define it `<char *, char *>` but I would have to define the hashing and other thing to work like that.

Is there any other option?

**EDIT. ADD MORE CONTEXT FOR THE PROBLEM:**

I will iterate another lists and get the values from the ordered_maps, I will know what type of data I'm using for the key and use that to generate a JSON string as result.

For more context the format of the files are like these:

```
INT number of fields to use. Example: 3
-- now there is a for from 1 to 3 as we have 3 fields
CHAR type of data (1 = int8, 2 = int16, 3 = int32, 4=string)
STRING name of the field
STRING alias of the field
-- end for
-- now I do a while not EOF
    -- for each field
        read value from file (int8, int16, int32, string) depending the type of field
        first item of the for will be the KEY
        if item != first add the value to an unoredered_map using the first as key
    -- end for
-- end while
```

Comment: The types are missing in your question...

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva I wonder how you would hash that.

Comment: @Quentin Check out the edit on the question. The types were literally not visible.

Comment: @SimonKraemer oh, my bad. It makes sense now :)

Comment: How are you going to use the `unordered_map` once the files have been read?

Comment: How about using a struct + union?

Comment: And how will you know how to cast the keys and values once your map is populated? You could use `void*` though I personally don't like it as it can get messy pretty easily.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of type erasure on the map. But without context, I can't be any more specific :)

Comment: Anastasiya Asadullayeva's suggestion of `boost::variant` is solid.  In the `unordered_map`, you could use one as the key, and a `vector` thereof as the value.  To hash, write you own function that switches on the key's `.which()` value (a 0 based index of the type stored), extract the value of that type and hash it using the Standard Library `std::hash` functions for integers and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a self defined type and void * for the data.

So I set the type of the var in the struct and the data for it.

Here is the result:

```
struct fieldVariant {
    char type;
    void * data;
    fieldVariant(char _type, void * _data) {
        type = _type;
        data = _data;
    }
};
struct fieldHash {
    inline size_t operator()(const fieldVariant * val) const
    {
        unsigned long h = 0;
        unsigned long varSize = 0;
        switch (val->type) {
            case INT8:
                varSize = 1;
                break;
            case INT16:
                varSize = 2;
                break;
            case INT32:
                varSize = 4;
                break;
            case INT64:
                varSize = 8;
                break;
            case INT128:
                varSize = 16;
                break;
            case CHAR2:
                varSize = ((string *)val->data)->length();
                break;
        }

        for (int i=0; i < varSize; i++)
            h = 5 * h + *(char *)(val->data + i);
        return size_t(h);
    }
};


struct fieldEql {
    inline bool operator()(const fieldVariant *s1,const fieldVariant *s2) const {
        unsigned long varSize = 0;
        switch (s1->type) {
            case INT8:
                varSize = 1;
                break;
            case INT16:
                varSize = 2;
                break;
            case INT32:
                varSize = 4;
                break;
            case INT64:
                varSize = 8;
                break;
            case INT128:
                varSize = 16;
                break;
            case CHAR2:
                return *((string *)s1->data) == *((string *)s2->data);
        }
        return memcmp(s1->data, s2->data, varSize) == 0;
    }
};

unordered_map<fieldVariant *, fieldVariant *, fieldHash, fieldEql> data;
void add(fieldVariant * key, fieldVariant * value) {data[key] = value;};
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you going to store inside the map and how are you going to choose it?

There are two practical solution to your problem:

#### Parametric Polymorphism

This is how you should try to solve your problem in the first place. By keeping the arguments of your `unordered_map` generic.

This is mostly done by having a structure like

```
class Reader {
  virtual void readFile(const std::string& name) = 0;
};

template<typename K, typename V>
class RealReader {
private:
  std::unordered_map<K,V> data;

public:
  void readFile(const std::string& name) override {
    K key = // read key;
    V value = // read value
    data[key] = value;
  }
};
```

#### Subtype Polymorphism

Define your own `Key` and/or `Value` classes so that you can define a `std::unordered_map<Key*,Value*>` and then subtype these custom types with your required types.

Without knowing how these are going to be used it's difficult to tell what's best.

Comment: Basically I will ready a file, the file with tell me the type of data i'm reading and the I will have to store that data in an unordered_map, the keys can be int8, int16, int32, and the values can be int8, int16, int32, string.
I will create an unordered map for each set of values so if the set i'm reading is int32, string, it will create an unordered_map for that.

Comment: Yes but once you have this `unordered_map` how are you going to use it?

Comment: I will iterate another lists and get the values from the ordered_maps, I will know what type of data I'm using for the key and use that to generate a JSON string as result

Comment: According to what you say going by parametric polymorphism and encapsulate all the behavior inside a `template<typename K, typename V>` should be the best solution

Comment: I added more context of the problem above. but I will research about the template. thank you!

Comment: The code presented under "Parametric Polymorphism" isn't a good fit as the types aren't known until after the file "header" has been read: some non-templated header parsing code could then call one of many instantiations for processing the rest of the file, but an issue is there's no particular reason to think "many" is going to be sensibly small - e.g. there are LOTS of permutations of types possible given 10 fields....